# Site Navigation - remove parent site from menu?

Tags: navigation

I'm using the 'Look and Feel' > 'Navigation' system to create my own menu for my public facing website. Rather than automatically show subsites or pages, I'm constructing the menu manually by adding my own headings and links. As such the 'Navigation Editing and Sorting' section of the 'AreaNavigationSettings.aspx' page shows something like this (where [this] indicates a 'heading' and > indicates a link)..

```
Global Navigation
  [Products]
    >Product 1
    >Product 2
    >Product 3
  [Services]
    >Service 1
    >Service 2
```

When this is rendered, the menu includes the parent site as the first item in the menu, such as

```
English US| Products | Services
```

Rather than show "English US", I'd rather show "Home". I can do this by changing the 'title' for the site, but we have 6 sites that act as parents, each with their own menu, and 4 of them would end up with titles of 'Home', making it confusing to know which site you're looking at in the 'Site Settings > Site Content and Structure' view (/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx).

Ideally I want to stop the parent site from being added automatically, and add a link manually for 'Home'. This would allow me to continue to title my sites 'English US' or 'English UK', so the structure view is more understandable.

Is is possible to remove the parent site from the menu, or stop the parent site from being added automatically?

(phew! long explanation for such a short question )

Cheers

kevin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have access to SharePoint Designer you can set the master page or page layout to also call a custom CSS file. In mine, I have the following:

```
.s4-tn ul.root > li.static > a {
    display:none;
}
```

This hides that first link.

Comment: Thanks 'ThatGuy' - I updated a typo (li.satic) and it worked a treat!

Comment: For other SharePoint CSS questions like this, I would recomment [this site](http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-base-css-classes.html). It's quite handy for seeing the CSS classes associated with different parts of the page.

Comment: I have the same requirement but not sure where and how to call this custom CSS file.Can @QMKevin help me?                              PS:I'm not a developer,so i request you to show me how and where to add this CSS file with indepth clarity.

Comment: in sharepoint 2013 .ms-breadcrumb-box should be replaced instead of .s4-tn

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'd have to have some CSS or jQuery to hide the first top link tab, td id of zz1_TopNavigationMenun0.  There isn't a method I know to hide it from the UI.

Here is a great blog article on some options for customizing the navigation controls, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/modonovan/archive/2008/05/30/custom-navigation-in-sharepoint-the-full-monty.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Eric. 'ThatGuy' provided the exact answer, but I'm sure your link would have taken me to the same conclusion :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple steps without modifying any codes and opening SharePoint Designer:

1. Click Edit Links on the page
2. click Cross button & remove the first **Home** link